# Android Studio - Enable VT-x in your bios setting

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

When ever I try to run an emulator I see this error
"Intel HAXM is required to run this avd
/dev/KVM is not found.
Enable VT-x in your BIOS security setting, ensure that your Linux distro has working KVM module'

I have already installed haxm through SDK successfully , Also I have enabled virtualization in the security tab. The thing that is confusing me now is why does it say Linux distro in the error message when I'm running windows 7 on a HAXM and VT supported PC?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32913219/5993410)

Comment: That's for windows 10 ...mine is 7

Comment: i also have same issue any solution?

Answer (score 4):

You have to enable virtualization technology in your computer's bios. Please visit [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/213795/how-to-enable-intel-vt-x-in-your-computers-bios-or-uefi-firmware/) for further instructions

Comment: I already did that anyway no prob since I have already fixed that. but now I have even a greater problem the emulator can only start when using software (not hardware) also it stuck at the android logo....is there any way to make the emulator run by the hardware....? when I try hardware it crushes

Comment: Windows 10 issue

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same problem. Today (13-11-17) I solved it.

These are the steps to solve the problem-

1)Go to Android Studio Preferences.
2)Appearance and Behavior --> System Settings --> Android SDK.
3)Copy the Android SDK location Path.
4)Go to the path.
5)In the path folder open "extras" folder then open "intel" then open "Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager"
6)The double-click on IntelHAXM_[version number here].
7)The Re-Install IntelHAXM. 
8) Open Emulator.

It should work fine.(It worked for me)

Comment: It didn't work out! Is it necessary to restart system or Android Studio?

Comment: This worked for me... lol That is strange though. Thank you mate

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using an Intel CPU, it's not gonna support HAXM no matter what you install.

Answer (score 0):

If you have AMD CPU:

1. Boot into BIOS by pressing F2 or delete (Asus Motherboard).
2. Click Advanced -> CPU Configuration -> SVM Mode, Enable SVM Mode
3. Save and Reboot